# Can I add a dynamic address in a makefile?

Tags: makefile, shared-libraries, abaqus

I'm creating a shared library using the following command:
`abaqus make library=myCode directory='/usr/abaqus'`

Inside the directory ( /usr/abaqus/ folder) I have an abaqus environment file to include additional shared libraries. Here is link_sl parameter in the env file:
`link_sl='LINK /nologo  %B /usr/Dassault Systemes/SimulationServices/V6R2019x/linux_a64/code/lib/ABQSMAOdbApi.so /usr/Dassault Systemes/SimulationServices/V6R2019x/linux_a64/code/lib/ABQSMAOdbCore.so ucrt.so'`

Now, here is the main problem. The location of ABQSMAOdbApi.so file is different in each computer. How can I use a dynamic address here or parametric value to take care of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. You haven't given us much to work with. Without knowing how you use this variable, or how you incorporate the env file, or how you want to control the address variable, I can suggest:

```
API_DIR = /usr/Dassault Systemes/SimulationServices/V6R2019x/linux_a64/code/lib

link_sl='LINK /nologo  %B $(API_DIR)/ABQSMAOdbApi.so /usr/Dassault Systemes/SimulationServices/V6R2019x/linux_a64/code/lib/ABQSMAOdbCore.so ucrt.so'
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The issue that I have is that this API_DIR address you mentioned here is different in every system. I need to create a routine to first, find the location as a parameter and then replace it with this API_DIR since I'm only providing the compiled file only. Then, when a user uses this library, first, my routine looks for a correct location and then replaces it and afterwards runs the code.

Answer (score 0):

Make allows you to set default values using:

`foo?=bar`

If in the command-line, you do not give `foo` a variable `make` will set it to `bar`